# Iterate through a list of types

Tags: c++, polymorphism

How can I iterate through a list of types without creating an instance of each type?

In my example, I have a parent class with a method, `getByName` which returns an instance of a child class. The `getByName` method is entirely broken since you cannot create an array of typedefs. What is the best way to make this work?

One solution is to create an array of `name` pointers, but this would get messy if there are multiple variables (more than just `name`) that I want to check against.

I basically want a clean solution that uses a loop rather than a series of if statements.

```
#include <string>

struct Number {
    Number(const std::string &name) :name(name) {}

    // fix me!
    static Number* getByName(const std::string &name) {
        typedef types[] = {
            One,
            Two,
            Three,
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            if (name == types[i]::name)
                return new types[i]();
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
    const std::string name;
};

struct One :Number {
    One() :Number(name) {}
    const static std::string name;
};

struct Two :Number {
    Two() :Number(name) {}
    const static std::string name;
};

struct Three :Number {
    Three() :Number(name) {}
    const static std::string name;
};

const std::string One::name = "one";
const std::string Two::name = "two";
const std::string Three::name = "three";
```

Comment: I recommend using a structure of names and function pointers; or `std::map` with name as the key and the function pointer as a value.

Comment: Search StackOverflow or the internet for "c++ factory implementation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store types directly in a meaningful fashion; however, you can store pointers to factory functions, which should be equally useful:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct Number;

Number* oneCreator();
Number* twoCreator();
Number* threeCreator();

struct Number {
    typedef Number* (*creatorFP)();
    typedef map<string, creatorFP> CreatorMap;

    static Number* getByName(const string &name) {
        // maybe initialise this map somewhere else
        CreatorMap creators;
        creators.insert(make_pair(string("one"), &oneCreator));
        creators.insert(make_pair(string("two"), &twoCreator));
        creators.insert(make_pair(string("three"), &threeCreator));

        CreatorMap::iterator creator = creators.find(name);
        if (creator != creators.end()) {
            return (*(creator->second))();
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    virtual void f() { cout << "NUMBER" << endl; }
};

struct One : Number {
    virtual void f() { cout << "ONE" << endl; }
};

struct Two : Number {
    virtual void f() { cout << "TWO" << endl; }
};

struct Three : Number {
    virtual void f() { cout << "THREE" << endl; }
};

Number* oneCreator() { return new One(); }
Number* twoCreator() { return new Two(); }
Number* threeCreator() { return new Three(); }

int main() {
    Number *two = Number::getByName(string("two"));
    two->f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! One thing I'm a little fuzzy on is `typedef Number* (*creatorFP)();`. What should I search for to understand this?

Comment: This is a typedef to simplify a pointer to function type definition. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295432/typedef-function-pointer

Comment: @cambunctious: Is with c++11 syntax clearer: `using CreatorF = Number* (); using creatorFP = CreatorF*;` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes but I like the one-liner :)

Comment: @cambunctious: one liner can also be done in C++11: `using CreatorF = Number* (*)();`.

Answer (score 3):

You may implement your factory as follow

```
template <typename T>
static std::pair<std::string, std::function<Number*()>> register_helper()
{
    return { T::name, []() { return new T{}; }};
}

static Number* getByName(const std::string &name) {
    static const std::map<std::string, std::function<Number*()>> factories = {
         register_helper<One>(),
         register_helper<Two>(),
         register_helper<Three>()
    };

    auto it = factories.find(name);
    if (it == factories.end()) {
        return nullptr;
    } else {
        return it->second();
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/OkxXIh)

Comment: Don't quite see why you're using `std::function` here. Should be fine with just `Number* (*)()`, no?

Comment: @dyp: `Number* (*)()` is possible here. I generally did the registration outside/public, so `std::function` allows capturing lambda in that case.

Comment: This is a really good answer but, in my case, the `register_helper` function is an over-simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Trying for something a little simpler then previous pitches, and assuming that getByName isn't called with an unsupported value all that often.

```
template <typename TYPE>
Number * factory()
{
    return new TYPE();
}

static const std::map<std::string, Number*(*)()> factories =
{
    {One::name, factory<One>},
    {Two::name, factory<Two>},
    {Three::name, factory<Three>}
};

static Number* getByName(const std::string &name) 
{
    try
    {
        return factories.at(name)();
    }
    catch (std::out_of_range &e)
    {
        // Log factory called with bad name as a hint that the programmer 
        // should check calling code.
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

But if calls with bad names are an expected use case, the hard way is much less expensive than handling the exception.

```
static Number* getByName(const std::string &name) 
{
    auto factory = factories.find(name);
    if (factory != factories.end())
    {
        return factory->second();
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Why is it "much less expensive" not to handle the exception?

Comment: There is a whole lot of stuff going on behind the scenes when an exception is thrown, much, much more than an if and an iterator compare. On the other hand, there is effectively no cost if the exception is not thrown and there is no checking code to contain bugs. If input of a bad name is truly exceptional, use the exception. The [second answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835817/are-exceptions-in-c-really-slow) and it's commentary explains. Whole thing's probably worth reading.